# Trying to understand why Availability Group replication being suspended didn't fire alert

Tags: sql-server, availability-groups, sql-server-2019

We are running SQL Server 2019 CU14 and last night we had one of our databases within a secondary Availability Group suspend replication due to the following reason:

> Always On Availability Groups data movement for database 'SomeDatabase' has been suspended for the following reason: "system" (Source ID 2; Source string: 'SUSPEND_FROM_REDO'). To resume data movement on the database, you will need to resume the database manually. For information about how to resume an availability database, see SQL Server Books Online.
>
> Error: 3313, Severity: 17, State: 2.
>
> During redoing of a logged operation in database 'SomeDatabase' (page (1:852127519) if any), an error occurred at log record ID (611475:530156:95). Typically, the specific failure is previously logged as an error in the operating system error log. Restore the database from a full backup, or repair the database.

Luckily we have replication latency alerts in place and were able to resume the synchronization before log space became an issue, however, I'm curious why this event wouldn't have triggered error 35264 (data movement suspended). We have the following alerts enabled on all our Availability Replicas. What am I missing or not understanding?

```sql
EXEC msdb.dbo.sp_add_alert
    @name = N'AG Data Movement - Suspended'
   ,@message_id = 35264
   ,@severity = 0
   ,@enabled = 1
   ,@delay_between_responses = 0
   ,@include_event_description_in = 1;
GO
EXEC msdb.dbo.sp_add_notification @alert_name=N'AG Data Movement - Suspended', @operator_name=N'DBAs', @notification_method = 1;
GO
```

Comment: Can the code for the above latency alert be shared? Thanks